# How do I make a script that cleans up objects from one document if they don't exist in another?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation

I have the following two collections, `Player` and `Team`. These two collections each contains lots of documents. Here is an example with some dummy data:

**Player**

```
_id: ObjectId('6098c5ab615d9e23543d0f6e'),
name: 'Frank',
age: 27,
position: 'striker'
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('61409537c4f113354782eea3'),
name: 'Jan',
age: 19,
position: 'midfielder'
```

**Team**

```
_id: ObjectId('61961ce8981cfc332fd71711'),
name: 'Team A',
players: [
    {
        refId: ObjectId('6098c5ab615d9e23543d0f6e'),
        goals: 13
    },
    {
        refId: ObjectId('61409537c4f113354782eea3'),
        goals: 6
    },
    {
        refId: ObjectId('61fcfb7d0fcb4d4c284bdefa'),
        goals: 2
    }
]
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('61fd27c152d4a56752b8f05c'),
name: 'Team B',
players: [
    {
        refId: ObjectId('6218a8af0486c46703414aba'),
        goals: 2
    },
    {
        refId: ObjectId('61409537c4f113354782eea3'),
        goals: 1
    }
]
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('56fd77c152d4a56752b8y89h'),
name: 'Team C',
players: [
    {
        refId: ObjectId('6413780af746f734b8720e5e'),
        goals: 9
    },
    {
        refId: ObjectId('6413781fab3a6458779aaa3f'),
        goals: 0
    }
]
```

I'm trying to make a clean up script that goes through all docs in my `Team` collection and pulls out the object if `players.refId` no longer exists in the `Player` collection. how can I do this?

So after the cleanup the teams would look like this:

```
_id: ObjectId('61961ce8981cfc332fd71711'),
name: 'Team A',
players: [
    {
        refId: ObjectId('6098c5ab615d9e23543d0f6e'),
        goals: 13
    },
    {
        refId: ObjectId('61409537c4f113354782eea3'),
        goals: 6
    }
]
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('61fd27c152d4a56752b8f05c'),
name: 'Team B',
players: [
    {
        refId: ObjectId('61409537c4f113354782eea3'),
        goals: 1
    }
]
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('56fd77c152d4a56752b8y89h'),
name: 'Team C',
players: [
]
```

So far I have this:

```
db.Team.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$players" },  
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Player",
            localField: "players.refId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "player"
        }
    },  
    { $match: { player: { $size: 1 } } },  
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            players: { $push: "$players" }
        }
    },
    { $project: { _id: 1, players: 1 } },
    { $merge: { into: "Team", on: "_id", whenMatched: "merge" } }
])
```

This solution works as long as there are at least one player in each team that exists in the `players` collection. When a team only has players that does not exist in the `players` collection, they are not cleaned up because `{ $match: { player: { $size: 1 } } }` filters them away. How do I solve this?

Comment: please make an attempt (and share [mcve]) before asking for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to do this:
First, there is a unwind/lookup/filter/group as in answer 1 (I think the match needs a small fix though (see my comment above).

I've stumbled onto a slightly better solution.

```
     // first get the player id's into one array
    [{$addFields: {
        player_id: {$map: {
           input: '$players',
            in: '$$this.refId'
           }}
    }},
{
    '$lookup': {
      'from': '$Players', 
      'let': {
        'lst': '$player_id'
      }, 
      'pipeline': [
        {
          '$match': {
            '$expr': {
              // using indexOfArray, so a missing player is -1
              // and an existing player has an index gt -1 
              '$gt': [
                {
                  '$indexOfArray': [
                    '$$lst', '$_id'
                  ]
                }, -1
              ]
            }
          }
        }, 
        {
          '$sort': {
            'name': 1
          }
        }
      ], 
      'as': 'x'
    }
  }]
```

I did this on my own data and changed the variable names since you didn't provide enough data for the test try [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/)

Comment: I'm not trusted enough to comment, but the test for match should be
{$match: {player: {$ne: null}}

Answer (score 2):

```
db.Team.aggregate([
  // Unwind the players array
  { $unwind: "$players" },
  
  // Lookup the player in the Player collection
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Player",
      localField: "players.refId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "player"
    }
  },
  
  // Filter out players that don't exist in the Player collection
  { $match: { player: { $size: 1 } } },
  
  // Group the players back into an array and replace the original players array
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      players: { $push: "$players" }
    }
  },
  
  // Project only the necessary fields
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      players: {
        refId: 1,
        goals: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution does not work. In the scenario of `Team C` where none of the players exist in the `Players` collection, it does not clean up the document. The `$match` stage is where it goes wrong.